# Python3: pickle a function without side effects

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, dill

I have a project with a function `foo` in a module `my_project.my_functions`. I want to pickle that function in a way that I can unpickle it from somewhere else without requiring to import `my_project`. `foo` does not have any side effect, so no dependencies outside the function.

I'm using `dill` to pickle `foo`, but dill is saving it as a `<function my_project.my_functions.foo>`, and complains about the unknown `my_project` module when I try to unpickle it.

Any solution?

Comment: `dill` can't handle the function reference to the uninstalled module.  You could install the module... then it would work.  Or, an alternative might be to use `dill` or `dill.source` and save the module first, then after that, save and store the function... but easiest is to install and import the module.

Comment: couldn't I hack the function to make it think it is referenced in `__main__` ?

Comment: Yeah, I think you could do that... in special cases `dill` modifies the reference for `__main__` in `globals`.  It needs to be done at (de)serialization time -- meaning, you'd more likely have to hack the `dill.Pickler` instead of your function.

Comment: This is a relevant issue: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/123, and I'm sure that there are others that are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by recreating the function from the code giving and empty `globals` dictionary.

#### In /my_project/module.py:

```
def f(n):
    return n+1
```

#### In my_project, before pickling the function:

```
import dill
import types
import module

f = types.FunctionType(module.f.__code__,{})

with open("my_func.pkl", 'wb') as fs:
    dill.dump(f, fs)
```

#### Somewhere else:

```
import dill

with open("my_func.pkl", 'rb') as fs:
    f = dill.load(fs)
```